# Improving efficiency on a tree "query"

Tags: performance, tree, depth-first-search

i've been assigend a task regarding the execution of certain queries on a generic Tree. The input is an undirected and connected graph with N nodes and N-1 arcs (basically a Tree), each with a certain cost, and the goal is to answer to Q queries regarding this structure.
Each query contains an additional arc for the graph (with a given cost), and the answer to a certain query is YES only if there is an arc (with a higher or equal cost) in the graph that can be substituted with it, maintaining the connectivity in it. 
For now, the solution i've come up with uses a DFS to find a path in the graph between the two ends of the arc contained in the query: if this path contains an higher (or equal) cost arc, then the answer is YES, otherwise it's NO. 
So each query is O(N), but i need to improve it drastically: i've been trying to use memory to use in some way the results of the previous queries, but nothing worked so far. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I think using a different data structure ([max heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap)) to store all the arcs will reduce your time complexity to O(1) for query and O(logn) for replace and restore the max heap(maintain the heap).

Your new steps can be:

1. during initialization, go through the tree (graph), and save all the arcs in a max heap. time complexity is O(n), as you have to iterate all the nodes. But as it is initialization, it is just once off cost.
2. during the query, just check the input with the max value of the
   heap, and the time complexity is O(1).
3. if the input cost is larger than the max value in the heap, then you just return NO.
   otherwise, you can return YES, and also replace the max node with the input arcs, and restore the max heap. O(logn) time complexity for the worst case.

Comment: I don't simply need to check if i have a higher cost arc, i need to maintain connectivity for this 'swap'.

Comment: If your arc data structure (class) has pointers to nodes, and a field to record the cost. You may only need to update the cost value of the object from the heap. And the graph is still valid as the linkage between nodes are not changed, the only value updated was the cost field.

Comment: Each query takes O(N) because of the DFS algorithm, i can already retrieve the cost of each arc in constant time, what i need to improve is just the path construction between two nodes (the ends of the arc that i received with this query).